# Which Event handler should i use for my windows application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

I have a mobile applciation thats interacts with a server. The mobile application should be allowed to do a http posting to the server.
The server should be able to handle the event and display out using a custom windows .net application on the server almost immediately based on event.

The http post will be in a asp.net webpage. From this page what type of application of event handling should i be used so that it can trigger a custom code in a c# windows application that i will be coding.

So what are the right ways to do it?

Is there any event handling that works on c#.net that can be applied on the above scenario?

So far i only thought of msmq event handling. The mobile app does a http post on the server, the server creates a msmq on the server side and the windows applications listens for the new msmq message.

Comment: Can you use Process to open an instance of the desktop app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use WCF to communicate with the desktop app.
It supports callbacks and events, which is exactly what you need.
see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx).